# How to top- align sidenotes using eledmac?

Tags: vertical-alignment, marginpar, eledmac

Eledmac commands `\ledleftnote` `\ledrightnote` `\ledsidenote` insert side notes at the level where the command was issued.
However the side note is bottom aligned, meaning the the note doesn't start at desired level, but ends at it.

Is there a way to make the start from the level where the command was issued and then downwards?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{eledmac, eledpar}

\begin{document}
\beginnumbering
\pstart 1. Ioannes  Brauus Chamissius Conimbricensis Doctor, Anathomicae lectionis
olim singularis; nunc uero medicae Cathedrae moderator subtilis et studiosus, eam pro
re presenti opinationem concepit, a qua, dum id efficaciter conaremur, eum dimouere
nequiuimus. Is lib. 1. De Medendis Corporum Malis toto cap. 7. fol. 23.  Citare deinde 
posset nonnullos etiam Dominos  Iuristas; ut Archidiac; et Bellameram ad cap. Non
liceat, 26. q. 5. quos citat , et probare uidetur Camillus
Gallinius\ledrightnote{margin note refers to Gallinius} lib. 2. de signific. uerb. 
cap. 17 et probant ex cap Nec  mirum, eadem causa, et q. ubi de Magis dicitur: Sine 
ueneni haustu, uiolentia tantum carminis interimunt etc. Supponiturque, daemonem sola 
vi naturali carminis operari: siquidem ipse non operatur, nisi applicando naturalia
actiua passiuis.
\pend
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)) for others to examine.  It makes it easier for you to attract help, and others to offer it.

Comment: as maintainer of eledmac, I try to do it from ... a long time. No find the way.

Comment: Sorry to read that. I'll use multiple footnotes--as soon as i find out how to ditch the footnotes' separator. Thanks anyway, Maieul, for this great package.

Comment: sorry, there was a solution. I answer to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am so stupid.

There is a solution, but not documented. And as your problem was not very different of an other problem for me, I answers too quick.

The solution, which I would now document, is to write on the preamble :

`\rightnoteupfalse
\leftnoteupfalse`